# Something like a tag cache and querying it for suggesting them using Redis

Tags: caching, redis, intersection

It would be like StackOverflow: when you ask a question you need to provide some tags.

Currently I'm querying the relational database store, but I believe that Redis should make sense in order to cache tag suggestions.

For example, it would be a set like this:

```
sadd tags:suggestions "c#" ".net" "redis"
```

Now some user is asking a question and he/she may write "ne" so there's some tag in the Redis cache that may match the whole partial tag name: **.net**.

I can't figure out how I would intersect such `tags:suggestions` Redis set in order to get ".net".

Or should I use a string instead of a set?

Thank you in advance!

### Note:

*For those asking "what I've tried so far", please double-check the question: **I can't figure out what to do, I'm just learning Redis***. **What I've tried so far? Reading the manual, trying it using a *set*, but I came here because I don't know if I can implement such requirement with Redis...**

Comment: @bicycle I don't know what to try, that's why I'm here. I got blocked because I thought I could do some kind of filters.

Comment: @bicycle By the way, if you check the question again... What I've tried so far? USING A SET...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After *googling* a lot, I found a good post about something that fits what I was asking for here at StackOverflow:

- http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/48851498400/redis-partial-word-match-you-auto-complete-me

Summary...:

#### 1. Create key-values for tags

```
sadd mysite:tags "stackoverflow" "stack-exchange" "question" "about-redis"
```

#### 2. Create an index for each possible combination

Yes, for example:

- "s"
- "st"
- "sta"
- ... and so on

  sadd mysite:tags:index:s 1 2

  sadd mysite:tags:index:st 1 2

  sadd mysite:tags:index:sta 1 2

  sadd mysite:tags:index:stack 1 2

  sadd mysite:tags:index:stacko 1

... and so on.

It's about adding all tags that start with **s**, **st**...

#### 3. Using SORT to get tags suggestions:

```
sort mysite:tags:index:s by nosort get tags:*
```

This will output:

- stackoverflow
- stack-exchange

Or...
    sort mysite:tags:index:stack- by nosort get tags:*

...will output:

- stack-exchange

---

It seems to be a good solution!