# Database equivalent to redis + rdbms

Tags: database, redis

I have a set of keys that store json-like data. For some period of time these keys are being frequently updated by my application, but after that they expire and will not be (or very rarely will be) updated again.
However there is a need to run aggregation-like queries (e.g. `SELECT SUM(value) FROM keys WHERE property1='...'`) on these "keys" throughout the history, including both expired and current keys.

At the present moment I use a combination of redis + sqlite. Redis stores current set of keys in memory. Then a job `scan`s redis, exporting data to sqlite.
When I need to run an aggregation query, I first run it on sqlite and then `scan` redis for additional values.

While this combo seem to work there are some annoyances:

1. the need to maintain two separate services. If for some reason redis stops working or the job fails or sqlite table gets corrupted, I end up in undefined state.
2. non-uniform api. I need to divide the query in parts, one for sqlite, one for redis, run them separately, process results separately and them combine them.
3. running queries against redis can be time-consuming, because there are no indexes for keys. Calling `keys` blocks the server, calling `scan` often ends up in too many iterations.

Is there a single database that would suit my needs? Maybe there are some configuration options for redis?

Answer (score 1):

Such operations should be developed in the application layer issuing Redis commands, and in some cases using Lua scripting.

If you model your data in an optimal way in Redis, you should be able to get the data as you need to later operate over it with your application layer language of choice (JavaScript, C#, Java, Python, Ruby...).

> running queries against redis can be time-consuming, because there are
>   no indexes for keys. Calling keys blocks the server, calling scan
>   often ends up in too many iterations.

This is a completely wrong statement. Redis is *the index* itself. Actually, it's like working with indexes directly.

You need to use its built-in data structures to index your data in order to be able to classify it and later retrieve subsets of your data based on custom application layer criterias.

> Is there a single database that would suit my needs?

Maybe you should take a look at Cassandra. A tabular NoSQL database which has aggregated functions. Or Mongo. There're many options out there but non of them will outperform Redis, which is the fastest one by far (**when the use case fits well with Redis, of course!**).

Comment: Could you describe in more details or give links on how to "model my data in optimal way in Redis" and "use its built-in data structures to index your data in order to be able to classify it"? I'm using redis as a key-value store. Maybe I'm wrong and there are indexes on keys, but a search by the pattern via `keys xyz*` takes about 2 seconds, during which the server is blocked. If I use `scan 0 xyz*` it takes about 50 seconds to iterate over all keys.

Comment: @xaxa It seems like you ignore that Redis keys can store sets, lists, hashes... You're not limited to string-string keys. See for example this Q&A where I auto-answered my question myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066462/something-like-a-tag-cache-and-querying-it-for-suggesting-them-using-redis

Comment: @xaxa There's no definitive answer for you on how to model your data, but take a look at this: http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Comment: No, I'm not storing strings, I'm storing hashes (`hset`, `hget`, etc). However, redis can neither store hash inside hash nor use hash as name of a key (only strings).

Comment: @xaxa This is when you need to enter to the brilliant world of using available tools in Redis to model your data and still be efficient when retrieving it. As I said previously in some comment, there's no definitive answer for your question. You need to use these data structures to index your data in many ways and then access your data efficiently.

Comment: @xaxa At the end of the day, SQL indexes are stored using data structures behind the scenes. With Redis, you need to build these indexes yourself, that's all